# Radio button's appearing one over another

Tags: html, css, radio-button, styles

I have custom radio buttons on my application. My issue is that currently the radio buttons display fine individually. When I try to have two of them in one line... They appear over each other instead of beside each other. I can't change my HTML and can only mess with the CSS. Any help will be appreciated. I was thinking it was due to the width of each label but giving it a low width had the same result.

HTML:

```
<label class="radio">
  <input type="radio">
  <span class="custom"><span>One</span></span>
</label>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.radio span.custom > span {
  margin-left: 22px;
}

.radio .custom {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 20px;
}

.radio input:checked + .custom:after {
  background-color: #0574ac;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 12px;
}

.radio input + .custom {
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.checkbox input:checked .custom {
  background-color: blue;
  border-color: blue;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/fz5vhwtx/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just edit label class so (just example) :

```
label {
  cursor: pointer;
  display:inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to positionate each individually go for this:

give every span an id tag and use it in your css:

```
#your_span_id{ position: absolute; left:0px; height:100px; }
#your_second_span{ position:absolute; left:35px; height:100px;}
```

now your radio buttons are in the same row next to each other :)

cheers

scriptmind.js